# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to return 18 random rows from an mysql database.
Sadly it only adds one to the array which  return, what am I doing wrong?

```
function get_random_items(){
    $this->connect();
    $random_items = $this->execute_query("SELECT * FROM Fds_items ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($random_items)){
        $key = (string)md5($design['url']);
        $response['designs'][$key] = array(
            "url" => (string)$row['url'],
            "name" => (string)$row['name'],
            "creator" => (string)$row['creator'],
            "key" => 'edits.php?username=' . $row['creator'] . '&key=' . $key
        );
    }

    return (isset($response) ? $response : false);
}
```

Would appreciate any kind of help.

```
$this->connect(); //database connection
$this->execute_query(); //execute query to database
```

Comment: Because `$design['url']` is not defined so you get the same result of `md5()` as the key each time thru the loop.

Comment: Omg, im such a idiot. Thank you alot! It worked :)

Comment: a question is `(string)md5($design['url']);` will give different values each time if i define `$design['url'] =1;`?

Comment: @A-2-A No it would always return `md5(1)` , what is your point?

Comment: Point is if still `$design['url']` will define under loop `$key = (string)md5($design['url']);` will always same and again he will get only last value not all 18 values. then why he said it worked?

Comment: Yes it gave me back 18 items.